# Como transformar uma Collection do Eloquent em um array simples?

Tags: laravel

Estou realizando uma consulta ao banco e está sendo devolvido uma Collection... Como faço para ao invés de ter que chamar `$role->role` para obter o valor da coluna, conseguir o mesmo comportamento chamando somente `$role`?

Código atual:

```
$roles = Role::all('role');

foreach ($roles as $role) {
    Gate::define($role->role, function ($user) use ($role) {
        return $user->roles->contains('role', $role->role);
    });
}
```

Comment: Tente Role::all('role')->toArray();

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode serializar Models e Collections através do comando `toArray()`

No seu caso ficaria: `$roles = Role::all('role')->toArray();`

Mas transformar seu collection em array não vai resolver o problema como você espera, pois o role que você acessa (`$role->role`) na verdade é a coluna do seu banco, dentro do seu objeto. A solução seria obter apenas o valor do campo que você quer:

`$roles = Role::pluck('role')->all()`

Mais informações:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck